# MySQL: Left join and column with the same name in different tables

Tags: mysql

Consider:

```
SELECT * FROM `product` left join category on product.category_id = category.id
```

This query works fine. But the problem is, both the product table and the category table have fields named "name" and "id". So when I fetch the result of this query, it gives me only one name and one id, but I want both id's and name's.

How can I do this without having to rename the fields?
Is it possible to return with custom names such as *product_name* and *category_name*?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can add aliases to the fields:

```
SELECT
    a.id,
    a.name,
    a.category_id,
    b.id AS catId,
    b.name AS catName
FROM
    product AS a
LEFT JOIN
    category AS b ON a.category_id = b.category.id
```

Answer (score 6):

Use the "AS" keyword like:

```
SELECT product.id AS pid, category.id AS cid ... FROM `product` left join category on product.category_id = category.id
```

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar problem working with MySQL in a Node.js project.

I found that if you still want to use `select *` instead of listing out all columns and using an alias, the following works:

```
SELECT *, category.id AS cId, category.name AS cName 
FROM product LEFT JOIN category ON product.category_id = category.id
```

In other words, just create aliases for the joined columns that have conflicting names. You don't need aliases on other columns or on the table names.

Comment: This answer is perfect for tables with high amount of columns. Just note that the query result will contain duplicated fields. Using the `AS` aliases together with `*` is going to return the specified columns twice.

Answer (score 4):

Use aliases with the `AS` keyword:

```
SELECT p.id AS product_id, p.name AS product_name, c.id AS cat_id, c.name AS cat_name
FROM `product` AS p
LEFT JOIN category AS c ON p.category_id = c.id
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT p.*,c.* FROM product p LEFT JOIN category c on p.category_id = c.id;
```

Comment: This will work. You *can* use aliases as all the others mention, but you don't need to.

Comment: This won't work in PHP. When I fetch the rows (mysql_fetch_assoc), it comes only ONE name and ONE id

Comment: Sorry yes you would need to access via fetch_row if you leave the * value. Otherwise it would be using alias for every duplicate field as mentioned in other posts.

Comment: You can also use mysql_fetch_array(), but in this case you would need to access data with indexes instead of associations (or keys).

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
SELECT product.id AS productid, 
       category.id AS categoryid, ...
FROM `product` left join category 
       on product.category_id = category.id
```

Comment: An explanation would be in order. E.g., what is the idea/gist? Please respond by [editing (changing) your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/10530269/edit), not here in comments (***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).

Answer (score 0):

No one has answered it so I am answering it.
If Table 1 has lots of columns like 20 columns and Table 2 has lots of columns like 20 columns. Then it is very tiresome to write a query like table1.a, table1.b

mysqli fetch assoc will return the columns of the right table if the column has same name. Easiest solution I found was to use table1.* in the select

```
SELECT table1.* FROM table1 LEFT JOIN table2 on table1.id=table2.id
WHERE table1.branch LIKE '%' and table2.branch LIKE 'City'
```

This will result in columns only from table1, left join and table2 columns were just for where clause.

Comment: Right idea, bad explanation. Technically incorrect. `SELECT` does not participate in `join/where`